# How can I convert nested dictionary to defaultdict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I convert nested dictionary to nested defaultdict?

```
dic = {"a": {"aa": "xxx"}}
default = defaultdict(lambda: None, dic)
print(default["dummy_key"])  # return None
print(default["a"]["dummy_key"])  # KeyError
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to either loop or recurse over the nested dictionary, through all of its levels.

Unless it's potentially ridiculously deep (as in hundreds of levels), or so wide that small performance factors make a difference, recursion is probably simplest here:

```
def defaultify(d):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d
    return defaultdict(lambda: None, {k: defaultify(v) for k, v in d.items()})
```

---

Or if you want it to work with all mappings, not just dicts, you could use `collections.abc.Mapping` instead of `dict` in your `isinstance` check.

---

Of course this is assuming you have a pure nested dict. If you've got, say, something you parsed from a typical JSON response, where there might be dicts with list values with dict elements, you have to handle the other possibilities too:

```
def defaultify(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return defaultdict(lambda: None, {k: defaultify(v) for k, v in d.items()})
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return [defaultify(e) for e in d]
    else:
        return d
```

But if this actually *is* coming from JSON, it's probably better to just use your `defaultdict` as an [`object_pairs_hook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) while the JSON is being parsed, rather than parsing it to a dict and then converting it to a defaultdict later.

There's an example in the docs of using an `OrderedDict` in place of `dict`, but that won't quite work for us—unlike `OrderedDict` and `dict`, `defaultdict` can't just take an iterable of pairs as its only argument; it needs the default value factory first. So we can bind that in, using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
d = json.loads(jsonstring, object_hook_pairs=partial(defaultdict, lambda: None))
```

---

And so on.

Comment: Thank you, It worked very well. Yes, I have list too, your advice is greatly helpful for me.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @MaikoOhkawa If you actually _are_ getting this from `json.loads` or similar, you might want to consider building it a `defaultdict` in the first place, instead of first building a `dict` and then converting it. For example, the [`json` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) explain how to make a decoder use `OrderedDict` instead of `dict` for every JSON object—you can do the same thing to make it use a `defaultdict`.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I tried it but an error occured.

    json.loads('{"a": {"aa": "xxx"}}', object_pairs_hook=collections.defaultdict)  # TypeError: first argument must be callable or None

Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @MaikoOhkawa You can't just use `defaultdict`, because it needs an extra first argument—but you can use, e.g., `functools.partial(defaultdict, lambda: None)`, or `lambda *args, **kw: defaultdict(lambda: None, *args, **kw)`. I'll edit this into the answer.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks so much! By the way, I submitted an edit for your last example to change `object_hook_pairs` to `object_pairs_hook`, got an error and spotted the mispelling.