# How to update values in nested dictionary if keys are in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

Let's say i have a list of keys

```
key_lst = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
```

and i have a value

```
value = "my_value"
```

and an example dict `my_dict` with this structure

```
{
"key1": {
    "key2": {
        "key3": "some_value"
        }
    },
}
```

How can I dynamically assign the new value in variable `value` to `my_dict["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]` by going thru / looping over my `key_lst`?

I can not just say `my_dict["key1"]["key2"]["key3"] = value` since the keys and the number of keys is changing. I always get the keys (the path that i have to save the value at) in a list...

The output I am looking for is `{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'my_value'}}}`. The dictionary structure is predefined.

I'm using Python 3.7

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? The code to answer is in the other thread, but conceptually I think the two questions are different. This is about *setting* a nested value while the link is focused on *getting* a nested value

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Predefined dictionary structure: [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

You can define a function using `functools.reduce` to apply `getitem` repeatedly and then set a supplied value:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

def set_nested_item(dataDict, mapList, val):
    """Set item in nested dictionary"""
    reduce(getitem, mapList[:-1], dataDict)[mapList[-1]] = val
    return dataDict

key_lst = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
value = "my_value"
d = {"key1": {"key2": {"key3": "some_value"}}}

d = set_nested_item(d, key_lst, value)

print(d)
# {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'my_value'}}}
```

Note `operator.getitem` is used to access `dict.__getitem__`, or its more commonly used syntactic sugar `dict[]`. In this instance, `functools.reduce` calls `getitem` recursively on `dataDict`, successively using each value in `mapList[:-1]` as an argument. With `[:-1]`, we intentionally leave out the last value, so we can use `__setitem__` via `dict[key] = value` for the final key.

---

#### Arbitrary dictionary nesting: [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

If you wish to add items at arbitrary branches not yet been defined, you can construct a `defaultdict`. For this, you can first [`defaultify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50013806/9209546) your regular dictionary input, then use `set_nested_item` as before:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dd_rec():
    return defaultdict(dd_rec)

def defaultify(d):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d
    return defaultdict(dd_rec, {k: defaultify(v) for k, v in d.items()})

dd = defaultify(d)

key_lst = ["key1", "key2", "key5", "key6"]
value = "my_value2"
dd = set_nested_item(dd, key_lst, value)

print(dd)

# defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
#             {'key1': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
#                          {'key2': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
#                                       {'key3': 'my_value',
#                                        'key5': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
#                                                    {'key6': 'my_value2'})})})})
```

Comment: This is a pretty cool answer. Mind explaining a bit more on your `set_nested_item` function for me?

Comment: But this assumes the particular structure already exists. What about setting new values? You will need a defaultdict, right? This cannot handle KeyErrors as it is.

Comment: @hqkhan, Added an explanation.

Comment: @coldspeed, Agreed, this doesn't handle `KeyError`. That said, not sure whether this is relevant for OP's requirements. For example, it's conceivable that the dictionary structure is *given* and you only want to set values; hence `KeyError` is what you *want*.

Comment: JESUS CHRIST! That's a nice solution. Dict structure is actually given and i would expect a `KeyError` if the key is not in there. BTW: Not a requirement but this is more than three times faster than @coldspeed's answer. This is the one, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessary to return `d` from `set_nested_item()` - the dictionary gets modified in-place already

Comment: For clarification, I believe `dd_rec` stands for "defaultdict recursive". The code is a bit odd to read, but it's the same concept from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702435/7446465)

Answer (score 6):

You can iteratively build/access levels using `setdefault` in a loop:

```
d = {}
d2 = d
for k in key_lst[:-1]:
    d2 = d2.setdefault(k, {})

d2[key_lst[-1]] = value
print(d)
# {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'my_value'}}}
```

`d` is the reference to your dictionary, and `d2` is a throw-away reference that accesses inner levels at each iteration.

Comment: Yes works perfectly. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
def update(d, key_lst , val):
    for k in key_lst[:-1]:
        if k not in d:
            d[k] = {}
        d = d[k]
    d[key_lst[-1]] = val

d = {}

update(d, list('qwer'), 0)
# d = {'q': {'w': {'e': {'r': 0}}}}
```

You could use `defaultdict` too, it's neat in a sense but prints rather ugly...:

```
from collections import defaultdict

nest = lambda: defaultdict(nest)
d = nest()

def update(d, key_lst , val):
    for k in key_lst[:-1]:
        d = d[k]
    d[key_lst[-1]] = val

update(d, 'qwer', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can loop through your keys like this :

```
d = {}
a = d
for i in key_lst: 
    a[i] = {}
    if i == key_lst[-1]:
        a[i] = value
    else:
        a = a[i]
print(d)
# {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'my_value'}}}
```

Edit: I guess I misread the question and answered as if the dictionnary wasn't already existing. [jpp answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54138200/5050917) is pretty neat otherwise I guess!

Answer (score 0):

```
key_lst = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
my_dict={
"key1": {
    "key2": {
        "key3": "some_value"
        }
    },
}

val=my_dict
#loop gets second to last key in chain(path) and assigns it to val
for x in key_lst[:-1]:
    val=val[x]
#now we can update value of last key, cause dictionary key is passed by reference
val[key_lst[-1]]="new value"

print (my_dict)

#{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'new value'}}}
```

Comment: @Julien what is half broken?

Comment: @Julien thats right thanks, but i can't see possibility of non existing key in question

Comment: I take that back. OP has clarified the dict structure is given in a comment to another answer... (wasn't the downvoter in the first place but upvoted to balance out :)

Comment: @Julien thanks, i was thinking to delete my answer,you know i'm new and i was late to submit this answer and didn't know there's similar answer. next time i'll submit carefully :)

Comment: Please add some comments around it explaining why this is an answer, and/or what problem this code solves.

Comment: @Kraang-Prime  comments added